# Regex match everything NOT + or - followed by one or more digits

Tags: regex

My regex needs to match the pattern

"Find everything NOT a line seperated by a newline return beginning with exactly zero or one + or- signs followed by Digits."

The opposite of this:

[+-]?[0-9]+

Except that doesn't quite work because it does not remove + or - found in the middle of a string.

Update for Examples and Language:

- -111243 (Match nothing)
- -113C45 (Match C)
- +434 (Match nothing)
- D356-295U (Match D-U)
- 93*&#94 (Match *&#)
- +432 +42 (Match space +)
- +432+42 (Match + in the middle, but not the + at the beginning)
- 22dd (Match dd)

I want to use it as a replace all command to remove any non-valid characters except signed integers or unsigned integers.

It is PCRE reg-exs http://www.pcre.org/

Comment: "Find everything NOT a line seperated by a space or newline return beginning with exactly zero or one + or- signs followed by Digits." is really unclear, could you show some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update*** *(based on comments)*

This is a PERL compatible one including a *negative lookbehind* :

```
\D+(?<!^[+-])
```

You can see the matches [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/gK9aP0/2):

[image]

Comment: Pretty close, the only issue is (And I didn't specify this use case) is where the non-numeric characters terminate the string.  E.g. 22dd!

Comment: @MichaelRyanSoileau then use `[^\d]+(?<!^[+-])`

Comment: `++434` matches `++` is that, what it should? However, nice one! :)

Comment: @Jonny5 Thanks! and also for that you can change `\D+` to `\D`